# Artifacts with rendering stochastic texture

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

When using a fragment shader to render a stochastic texture, artifacts in the form of lines appear. At what stage of the code can this occur, is it possible to shift the extreme UV coordinates?

```c
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
        
vec2 hash2D2D (vec2 s){
    return fract(sin(mod(vec2(dot(s, vec2(127.1, 311.7)), dot(s, vec2(269.5,183.3))), 3.14159))*43758.5453);
}

vec4 tex2DStochastic(sampler2D tex, vec2 UV){
    mat4x3 BW_vx;
    vec2 skewUV = mat2x2(1.0 , 0.0 , -0.57735027 , 1.15470054) * UV;
    vec2 vxID = vec2(floor(skewUV));
    vec3 tNoise = vec3(fract(skewUV), 0);
    tNoise.z = 1.0 - tNoise.x - tNoise.y;   
    
    if(tNoise.z > 0.0){
        BW_vx = mat4x3(
            vec3(vxID, 0),
            vec3(vxID + vec2(0, 1), 0),
            vec3(vxID + vec2(1, 0), 0),
            tNoise.zyx
        );
    }else{
        BW_vx = mat4x3(
            vec3(vxID + vec2 (1, 1), 0),
            vec3(vxID + vec2 (1, 0), 0),
            vec3(vxID + vec2 (0, 1), 0),
            vec3(-tNoise.z, 1.0-tNoise.y, 1.0-tNoise.x)
        );
    }

    return  texture2D( tex, (UV + hash2D2D(BW_vx[0].xy)) ) * (BW_vx[3].x)+
            texture2D( tex, (UV + hash2D2D(BW_vx[1].xy)) ) * (BW_vx[3].y)+
            texture2D( tex, (UV + hash2D2D(BW_vx[2].xy)) ) * (BW_vx[3].z);
}


vec4 color = tex2DStochastic(uTexture, vUv*5.0);
```

[image: output]

I tried to change the texture minFilter parameters - it did not help.